# Why can I not use find + awk to find the largest file in the filesystem?

Tags: shell, awk, files, find, command

Why does this not work?
`find / -ls 2>/dev/null | awk '$7 > max {max = $7}; END {print max}'`
This does work:
`find / -printf "%s\n" 2>/dev/null | sort -nr |head -n1`

In the first one, $7 is the size of the file, so idk why it doesnt work

Comment: Is there no output at all or is the output a wrong file size? Does it work if you choose a different directory?

Comment: Try changing `$7 > max` to `$7 > max+0` and you'll probably get output but it's also probably not to be trusted. Now try running `find / -ls 2>/dev/null | awk '$7 != $7+0` to see any lines of the `find` output where `$7` is not a number as you expected.

Answer (score 4):

You won't get the size in the 7<sup>th</sup> field in `find / -ls` output:

- for device files where you get the device major number instead
- if the user or group name contains blank characters
- if file paths (including targets of symlinks) have newline characters.

Also beware that some of those files may be virtual. For instance `/proc/kcore` on my system is 128TiB large, the system's virtual memory address space.

Also apparent size is not the same as disk usage. `truncate -s15T file` creates a 15TiB sparse file that takes no space on disk for instance. Use `%b` if you want to find out the file that takes most space on disk.

Beware that if there are ties, which one you'll get will vary between those too approaches.

```
find / -xdev -printf '%b %p\0' 2> /dev/null |
  sort -zk1rn | head -zn1 | tr '\0' '\n'
```

(heaviest and if ties first in lexical order)

Or:

```
find / -xdev -printf '%b %p\0' 2> /dev/null|
  awk -v max=-1 -v RS='\0' '
    $1 > max {max = $1; out = $0}
    END {if (max >= 0) print out}'
```

(heaviest, random one if ties).

The disk usage is expressed in number of 512 byte units. Note that files in directories you don't have read or search access won't be considered.

`-xdev` restricts the search to one file system, here the root filesystem.

Note that `-printf`, `-z` are GNU extensions. `-v RS='\0'` is also non-standard.

To report all ties (in no particular order):

```
find / -xdev -printf '%b %p\0' 2> /dev/null |
  awk -v max=-1 -v RS='\0' '
    $1 == max {out = out ORS $0; next}
    $1 > max {max = $1; out = $0}
    END {if (max >= 0) print out}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I got this working though:

```
sudo find /boot -ls | awk '$7 > max {name = $11 ; max = $7}; END {print name" "max}'
```

Comment: awk has a builtin variable `OFS` so you don't have to hard-code separators in the output - instead of writing `print name" "max` you can write `print name, max` and the `,` will be replaced by whatever string you set `OFS` to, a blank char by default. `name = $11` will fail if any file name contains blanks.